# Define how function behaves, dependant on what name is passed in

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have created a function, but depending on what name is passed into the function, I'd like the function to behave differently

Created function takes in a dataframe, creates a pivottable and scale some columns by 100 or 0.01. For a particular type of dataframe (which contains a particular column), I do not want the Avg Weight to be scaled. Is there a way to find the name of the df passed?

edit:

all df have the same column names, so to differentiate the "SpecialDF" from others is only by its name passed into the function. At this point should i be looking at classes or decorators? the def scale(df) function is quite long and only this part requires special handling

```
def scale(df):

    dfpvt= pd.pivot_table(df, values=['Avg Wt', 'Avg Spd'], index=y,aggfunc='sum')

    dfpvt.loc[:['Avg Wt', 'Avg Spd']=dfpvt[['Avg Wt', 'Avg Spd']].apply(lambda x: x/100)

    return dfpvt
```

what i'm looking for is something like

```
def scale(df):

    dfpvt= pd.pivot_table(df, values=['Avg Wt', 'Avg Spd'], index=y,aggfunc='sum')

    if df==SpecialDF:
        dfpvt.loc[:['Avg Spd']=dfpvt[['Avg Spd']].apply(lambda x: x/100)
    else:
        dfpvt.loc[:['Avg Wt', 'Avg Spd']=dfpvt[['Avg Wt', 'Avg Spd']].apply(lambda x: x/100)
    return dfpvt
```

Comment: Having a specific column doesn't make a DF diifferent type, it will still be the same DF, if you ant to check a specific col, pass it's name as an input to function and check if it there in DF col names, if yes then apply your operation else common operation

Comment: to add on, all df have the same column names, so to differentiate the "SpecialDF" from others is only by its name passed into the function. At this point should i be looking at classes or decorators? the def scale(df) function is quite long and only this part requires special handling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For a particular type of dataframe (which contains a particular
>   column), I do not want the Avg Weight to be scaled.

Use an `if` or ternary statement to determine whether a column exists in your dataframe:

```
def scale(df):
    dfpvt = pd.pivot_table(df, values=['Avg Wt', 'Avg Spd'], index=y, aggfunc='sum')
    scale_cols = ['Avg Spd'] if 'some_col_label' in df else ['Avg Wt', 'Avg Spd']
    dfpvt.loc[: scale_cols] /= 100
    return dfpvt
```

The idea is to reduce repeated code and only modify the most basic objects required to change the required columns, in this case a `list` object.

For a more generic function, you can have `scale_cols` as an argument and [`pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html) your dataframe through the function:

```
def scale(df, scale_cols):
    dfpvt = pd.pivot_table(df, values=['Avg Wt', 'Avg Spd'], index=y, aggfunc='sum')
    dfpvt.loc[: scale_cols] /= 100
    return dfpvt

df = df.pipe(scale, ['Avg Spd'] if 'some_col_label' in df else ['Avg Wt', 'Avg Spd'])
```

---

> all df have the same column names, so to differentiate the "SpecialDF"
>   from others is only by its name passed into the function.

Your updated requirement is *completely* different. Names are just references: do **not** rely on them for processing conditions. Good practice is to use a dictionary to store your dataframes and use keys in your dictionary to identify a "special" dataframe:

```
dfs = {'df1': df1, 'df2': df2}

def scale(df, scale_cols):
    dfpvt = pd.pivot_table(df, values=['Avg Wt', 'Avg Spd'], index=y, aggfunc='sum')
    dfpvt.loc[: scale_cols] /= 100
    return dfpvt

key = 'df1'
dfs[key] = dfs[key].pipe(scale, ['Avg Spd'] if key == 'df1' else ['Avg Wt', 'Avg Spd'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the term "type" of DataFrame, you would want `isinstance` ([documentation here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance)).

However, since you say "which contains a particular column", you probably actually mean `if col in df`, where `col` is the name of that particular column.